# Closing dialog automatically, after firestore response in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a dialog box in which I'm animating a CircularProgressIndicator, it loads when firebase authentication is being carried out. It all goes fine unless login fails for some reason like (no internet, wrong email/password), app show error dialog then this dialog box keeps displaying unless I tap outside the box. I want this to automatically close if another dialog box or error box appears.

```
Future signIn()async{

try {
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) =>
        AlertDialog(
          title: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: Colors.deepOrange,
            ),
          ),
        )
    );

  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: emailController.text,
    password: passwordController.text,
  );

  fetchData();
  // print(role_firestore);
  if ( role_firestore == 'Admin'){

    return Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AdminHomePage()));
  }else if (role_firestore == 'User'){
    return Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>  MainPage()));
  }else if (role_firestore == 'Restaurant'){
    return Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
   Restaurants()));
  }else {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  final result = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
  showConnectivitySnackBar(result);
  handleLoginError (e);

}

}
```

and this is the dialog box which shows firestore errors

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (context)=> AlertDialog(
  title: const Text("Log In Failed",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange)),
  content: Text(messageToDisplay,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange)),
  actions: [TextButton( onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: 
  true).pop();},
    child: const Text("Ok",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange)),)],
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can close/pop your dialog by calling:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

just put it at the end of the method where the data is loaded when the try succeed
and in the start of the catch if an error got caught

Comment: it worked. this idea never crossed my mind. thanks